# Get extended property Microsoft graph mailFolders

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

This is maybe a very dumb question but I am trying to create a hidden folder with multiValueExtendedProperties.
If I´m creating the folder like this:

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders

```
{
    "displayName": "Test",
    "isHidden": "true",
    "multiValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "id": "StringArray {66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00050ec6ac6e} Name Recreation",
            "value": [
                "Food",
                "Hiking",
                "Swimming"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The result is:

[image: Post command]

Looks good to me?!

But if I check the `multiValueExtendedProperties`, I`ll get no properties?

[image: Get command]

I want to use this with Powershell and I suspect, that if the return is not visible in Graph Explorer, I'll also not get it working in Powershell?!

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the image you posted the Get request is missing the & between includehiddenfolders $expand in your query parameter eg you should have something like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox?includehiddenfolders&$expand=multiValueExtendedProperties($filter=id+eq+'StringArray+0x36E8')
```

The context in the response should be something like

```html
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('150bb06c-1c9a-4ac2-8b55-xxxxxxxx')/mailFolders(multiValueExtendedProperties())/$entity"
```

which means your extendedproperty definition got passed through in your example it just ignored an invalid query string (instead of returning an error which would have been more helpful)

Comment: What does this have to do with the error "code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token is empty."  Where is the OP requesting the token?

Comment: Hi Glen. Thank you. Looks like I changed to many things at once.